# Making a custom cumsum for Python, by using my own step in-between

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on making a custom Van Westendorp calculator and to make graphs in powerpoint I need to calculate cumulative frequencies. However, I don't want those frequencies to only be per prices (column A):[image]. If I did, I would simply use the cumsum() function on the column B, representing their frequencies.

I want to calculate cumulative frequencies (to the column D), where previous frequencies are calculated based on the column C value. In this case, the "step" is 2 (0, 2, 4 etc.). So in the column D I calculate only frequencies from the column B, if the value in the column A for that row is <= the value from the column C.

Is there a way to modify cumsum() function or write my own to do that? Essentially, what I want to achieve is this in excel:

[image]

I tried to make my own algorithm but it's not working properly

Comment: Can you post your pseudocode logic (or) your code effort so people can advise/point out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom function using `apply`

When you have two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'A':[0.5, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 5.99, 6, 7.5], 
    'B':[0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0]
    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':range(0, 10, 2)})
```

To get the `D` column you apply a custom function to `df2` where you filter `df` based on the value of the `D` compared to `A`:

```
df2['D'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['A'] <= x.C, 'B'].sum(), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
    C   D
0   0   0
1   2   4
2   4   11
3   6   17
4   8   17
```